# Infer conditional return generic types by object property

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to infer the generic type of `Model` per property. Everything currently is showing as `unknown[]` instead of the desired types in the comments below.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&noImplicitThis=false&noImplicitReturns=false&alwaysStrict=false&target=7&jsx=0&module=1&ts=4.2.3#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEANJBvAsAKB0p8ANiFFEgLID2AJhIQDwAqAfBkgL455IAuAnjGQBBAE4BzAK6RgPRgIhNWAXiSMkEAB48IwamSq0GAS2AAzCCNUBJYMAusA-BRp0mNuyNYAuJAApu%20Gqa2rr6LsZmFta29gDaALpITgaujO5xiT52AG4W3ACUANxc2Pj8gkgAShA8EiLAcoKKSCpBWjp6zob0JuaWaTGeSdEeCUg%20-qX4qurtoV2uvVEDHsxjTisWCWNZELkiBcW4U-CUwFA8vNCXKm6DADSqAGoghBLIwR1kopLSsvJ3VaPNohTrVU4iaj0C4iExiYEvN4QZjMXxgcJQHyMfI%20cGUSH0ADWED4lFMqke1Vq9UaCkYiPeKJarCwU3wIhqdWAR3wnGO%20FO50uwCkACMLClCC0kHYAO4LBgisDizy%20IrcQUXJAwuGS6VyhXQniw4BiVHqk5nLWioxiEw8PUqA2S%20g2u0yc1HDVWy4cqASQg3K4XXys6ZIGAiSgwACMPliSpVkseiYl4RTYrThni9wCEajMAATPGdabJTm85HowBmHylsTJysFgAs8dTImTMszHfTXeVWbojzd9vLubZ%20ejAFY68bdeFuOwLdwAPTLzSCeDaai8eRQbh%20gM8AB0VdjSFXfZV23i%20%20gh5PBcL5%20X2tnpuvt-9gYfNefr5NYgJJ%2096ns2f6%20O2SAAD5IMOMj5B%20UwHt%20p6Tn%209ZAfyz4ILUrw7oIe5IXeKEFjGf4SMAhLAJQsrAJh7LEcep5PheFFUTRdE3kRX5MQW1bkZR1G0fRSDIbx0ZgaxgkcSJYk-jAaFSexwlcTg7BAA)

```js
class Model<T> { x?: T }

type ArgumentType<T> = T extends Model<infer TInner> ? Model<TInner> : (
        T extends Model<infer TInner>[] ? Model<TInner>[] : never
    );

type ReturnType<T> = T extends Model<infer TInner> ? TInner[] : (
        T extends Model<infer TInner>[] ? TInner[][] : never
    );

const test = <TInner, TValue extends ArgumentType<TInner>, T extends Record<string, TValue>>(models: T): Record<keyof T, ReturnType<TValue>> => {

        return;
    }

const numberModel = new Model<number>();
const stringModel = new Model<string>();
const bigintModel = new Model<bigint>();

const result = test({
    prop1: [numberModel, numberModel, numberModel],
    prop2: [stringModel],
    prop3: stringModel,
    prop4: [numberModel, numberModel, numberModel, bigintModel],
    prop5: stringModel
});

//expected types
result.prop1 // number[][]
result.prop2 // string[][]
result.prop3 // string[]
result.prop4 // (number | bigint)[][]
result.prop5 // string[]

//actual types
result.prop1 // unknown[]
result.prop2 // unknown[]
result.prop3 // unknown[]
result.prop4 // unknown[]
result.prop5 // unknown[]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mZGbKW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz sorry about that! Original post updated with playground link

Comment: Uh, why are we turning all the `--strict` stuff off? That's up to you but it's not recommended.  Is there a reason your `Model<T>` class is not structurally dependent on `T`?  [That is not a good idea](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).  Is there a reason your `test` function has three generic type parameters, only one of which can be inferred from anywhere?  I suppose the question would involve rewriting the call signature for `test`, but that effort is stymied until I understand the other issues.

Comment: All I want is to see are the "expected types" when I hover over the props.

Comment: It could be that [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPZxeN) is what you're looking for, but I've done something with `T` in `Model<T>` and turned back on the strict checking.  If that works for you I can write up an answer, assuming you first [edit] the question to be a better [mre] with a structural dependence of `Model<T>` on `T`.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't look like you engaged with most of the questions in my comments.  Well, I'll check back later to see if they were addressed. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz holy shit that works perfectly! thanks you ! will mark as accepted

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your question code to be a better [mre]?

Comment: go right ahead !

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for your `test()` function would be to give it the following call signature:

```
declare const test: <T extends Record<keyof T, Model<any> | Model<any>[]>>(
  models: T
) => { [K in keyof T]:
    T[K] extends Model<infer U> ? U[] :
    T[K] extends Model<infer U>[] ? U[][] :
    never
  }
```

Note here that we have just a single [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T`, correponding exactly to the type passed in for the `models` function parameter.  This `T` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Record<keyof T, Model<any> | Model<any>[]>`, meaning that it can have any keys whatsoever, but its property values must all either be a `Model<X>` for some `X`, or an array of `Model<X>` for some `X`.  This is a fairly direct and specific constraint.

In your original version you had three type parameters, each of which was constrained to some type function of another, but TypeScript's compiler is unable to do inference that way.  If you have type parameters `U, V extends F<U>, W extends F<V>` you *might* get inference if you give the compiler a value of type `U`, but it is essentially impossible to do it if you only give the compiler a value of type `W`.  It can't run the engine backwards to make `W` do something to `V` and then make `V` do something to `U`.  A single type parameter is a lot easier to work with.

Then note that the output type

```
{ [K in keyof T]:
    T[K] extends Model<infer U> ? U[] :
    T[K] extends Model<infer U>[] ? U[][] :
    never
}
```

is essentially your ([unfortunately named](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype)) `ReturnType<>` type alias but [mapped over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the properties of `T`.  For each property key `K` in the type `T` corresponding to `models`, we take the property value type `T[K]` and do something like your `ReturnType<T[K]>`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const numberModel = new Model<number>();
const stringModel = new Model<string>();
const bigintModel = new Model<bigint>();

const result = test({
  prop1: [numberModel, numberModel, numberModel],
  prop2: [stringModel],
  prop3: stringModel,
  prop4: [numberModel, numberModel, numberModel, bigintModel],
  prop5: stringModel
});

/* const result: {
    prop1: number[][];
    prop2: string[][];
    prop3: string[];
    prop4: (number | bigint)[][];
    prop5: string[];
} */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyD2ATApiAPAFQHzQN7QA8B+ALmg2gF8BYAKDpVDACdlph4A7CAF2h+S8ymaMgIDOiGACVkHZojQBrZAE94AM3IAaOElRownVTgA+elOiMmA2gF0sWABR1o0ALb6QEMhjoBKaABeHHwbAGloAEtOaBV1LQw7Elc3cgi7UXFkSRgESzQYjWRmaABVHCJy+2gU2jT08MyxCSkLAyKS8qwaqrL7GrqGzmQANxLUmnpaDm4+TgBXdwAjEvzUYOgRgHd29EWVkud-AG46Wd5oXmYYgHN1kE2dvbRru+Ozma5L5ajbmJ4DyeyF2DzQv3+nB4Hzo52+fFYEAWID4QX4gh4TlwqQADsx4DiAIxkGwHVbMB66MlrLxUpbkh52bS4-E4gBMJLenHuXiZLIJAGYyFyeZZmfVoHiCQAWEnUim0rb0mlipWHBWqiEAxnitxSnEAVmFPBu3IedEop1htAA9AAqdjw6CI5E8MjYiV61nEtXkgZ2T4NfUcq4mu7+wNpfVC0Om272SNemVkJzy6DmLVQ-wR1JJw3GuMJi3QO02uhAA)